# ImportError: No module named PIL using py2app

Tags: python, py2app

I'm trying to create a mac app from python files.  I'm running into an "ImportError: No module named PIL" error.  Please note that PIL is installed and this script runs correctly when run from the command line.  I'm trying to make it into a osx application.  When I run the osx application I created from py2app I get the following error.

I've tried:

```
'includes': ['PIL']
```

And

```
'packages': ['PIL']
```

And

```
'modules': ['PIL']
```

How do I properly include PIL?

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['Sandwich.py']
APP_NAME = "asdfasdf"
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'iconfile': 'app.png',
    'includes': ['PIL']
    } 

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

**Sandwich.py**

```
import sys
import time
from PIL import ImageGrab

while(1):
    print "Chekcing in"
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Error**

```
9/22/16 3:13:23.736 PM PAssist[28192]: Traceback (most recent call last):
9/22/16 3:13:23.736 PM PAssist[28192]:   File "/Users/joeyz/Projects/SandwichApp/dist/PAssist.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 351, in <module>
9/22/16 3:13:23.736 PM PAssist[28192]:     _run()
9/22/16 3:13:23.736 PM PAssist[28192]:   File "/Users/joeyz/Projects/SandwichApp/dist/PAssist.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 336, in _run
9/22/16 3:13:23.736 PM PAssist[28192]:     exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
9/22/16 3:13:23.736 PM PAssist[28192]:   File "/Users/joeyz/Projects/SandwichApp/dist/PAssist.app/Contents/Resources/Sandwich.py", line 3, in <module>
9/22/16 3:13:23.736 PM PAssist[28192]:     from PIL import ImageGrab
9/22/16 3:13:23.736 PM PAssist[28192]: ImportError: No module named PIL
9/22/16 3:13:23.796 PM PAssist[28192]: PAssist Error
9/22/16 3:13:23.796 PM PAssist[28192]: 2016-09-22 15:13:23.796 PAssist[28192:10044666] PAssist Error
```

Comment: Is `PYTHONPATH` set up correctly? Also try the `--use-pythonpath` option.

Comment: Getting the same issue with --use-pythonpath, trying to figure out how to setup PYTHONPATH...

Comment: Can you try to import using `from . import PIL`?

Comment: Where? The setup file?

Comment: At the Sandwich.py file.

Comment: "from . import PIL" gives me Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sandwich.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import PIL
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
Pako-2:SandwichApp pako$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the install_requires keyword within setup. This has the additional benefit of installing the package(s). In your case I would use `install_requires=['pillow']` and pip will automatically grab pillow during the installation process. This still having PIL in the packages specified above as you did.  Got the answer from issue: [39649714]

```
setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
    install_requires=['pillow'],
)
```